# convert datetime object to string Python

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch

I need to create strings of the form yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ to store a Python datetime object in elasticsearch (basic_date_time). This seems to be a standard time string, but I have trouble to make elasticsearch accept the date? I think I am getting my datetime -> string conversion wrong? I am using

```
datetime_object.strftime("%Y%m%d'T'%H%M%S")
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here? Also is there a way to create std. datetime strings rather than using .strftime()?

thanks
carl

Comment: Your format string doesn't have milliseconds or timezone. Look up the docs for `strftime()` to get the appropriate format options.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following to get the `basic_date_time` of Elasticsearch with 3 digits of milliseconds:

```
d = datetime_object.astimezone()
d.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f")[:19] + d.strftime("%z")
```

Which gives `"20180124T103350.376+0100` for `datetime_object = datetime.now()`

Comment: `.astimezone()` adds local time zone info. You need that only if the object does not already contain `tzinfo`. `d.strftime("%Z")` (with uppercase Z) gives the time zone name, which is included in the output string. In ElasticSearch, the Z stands for the zone offset, so I correct the answer with lowercase z, which is what is used in python for the zone offset.